# Java 8 method references: provide a Supplier capable of supplying a parameterized result

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to use

```
java.util.Optional.orElseThrow()
```

with an Exception type that asks for a constructor parameter. Something like this:

```
.orElseThrow(MyException::new(someArgument)) // obviously NOT working
```

Is there a way to create a Supplier that passes my argument value in?

Comment: Why can't you do `orElseThrow(() -> new MyException(someArgument))`?

Comment: Professional Java programmer with plenty of streams & Optional experience…I still end up here sometimes.  And this is why I prefer Kotlin.

Answer (score 608, accepted):

Sure.

```
.orElseThrow(() -> new MyException(someArgument))
```

Answer (score 26):

It appears that you can throw only RuntimeException from the method `orElseThrow`.  Otherwise you will get an error message like  `MyException cannot be converted to java.lang.RuntimeException`

**Update**:-   This was an issue with an older version of JDK.  I don't see this issue with the latest versions.

Comment: thanks, this was throwing me off when using `Optional` in groovy.  Trying to `throw Exception` from a groovy closure, but it failed with `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException`, changing to a `RuntimeException` fixed it.

Comment: Good to know about that. Fortunately in my case, I'm using RuntimeExceptions, but this may not always be the case.

Comment: **Incorrect** according to the class documentation for [`Optional.orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) which says you can throw a [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) which means an `Error` or any `Exception`.

Comment: I think this was an issue with an older version of JDK 8.

Comment: @Manu Perhaps you are referring to [JDK-8047338](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8047338) discussed on this Question, [*Throw RuntimeException inside Stream with Optional.orElseThrow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39076077/642706). If so, include in your Answer. I've not had quite enough coffee to discern if this is spot-on or not, so I'll refrain from editing your Answer myself.

Answer (score 13):

```
optionalUsers.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
```

Comment: i am getting error "  The method orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X>) in the type Optional<QueryEntities> is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {}) "