# what does the lambda expression in orElseThrow substitute?

Tags: java, exception, lambda, option-type

Let's taken some simple example code:

```
Employee employee = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
```

From my understanding, the lambda is used to create a subistute of a functional interface (only 1 method), and empty parenthesis means that the method has no parameters.

But what method is called in orElseThrow that a lambda is needed? I thought it is either an `Optional` or an `Exception`.

So my question is: How would this look like without a lambda call?

Employee class:

```
class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

and the exception class:

```
class EmployeeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    EmployeeNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super("Could not find employee " + id);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I am interested in how to write a valid, compilable substitution for the lambda- expression.
Right now I am at

```
        Employee employee = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            new Supplier<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public Throwable get() {
                    return new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                }
            }
        )
```

but that is not right, since now I would need to add the exception to the method signature, which is not the case when using the lambda..it shows that I don't know how to implement the supplier class by hand instead of just skipping all that by the use of lambdas

Comment: What search and research have you done prior to asking? Looked at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)), for example? Please when asking search and research first, and tell us what you found and how it was insufficient. It makes for better questions — and for better answers, so it’s for your own sake.

Comment: Related: [Java 8 method references: provide a Supplier capable of supplying a parameterized result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917138/java-8-method-references-provide-a-supplier-capable-of-supplying-a-parameterize).

Comment: I have read the documentation, but my java knowledge is a bit rusty and I am having a hard time understanding what exactly is substituted. 
I don't know how to write orElseThrow without the lambda, e.g. putting in the supplier as anonoymous class there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tested, but I believe that to avoid having to handle a general `Throwable` (by declaring it in your method signature or catching it within your enclosing method) you need to provide a `Supplier<RuntimeException>` or similar with an even more specific type than `RuntimeException`. For example:

```
    Employee employee = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
        new Supplier<EmployeeNotFoundException>() {
            @Override
            public EmployeeNotFoundException get() {
                return new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
            }
        }
    );
```

Since `EmployeeNotFoundException` is a `RuntimeException` and thus an unchecked exception, with the above the compiler won’t care whether you handle the exception.

You have read the documentation correctly, at least partially: What we are passing to `orElseThrow` is a `Supplier`, so this is the interface that the lambda implements and the interface we need to implement no matter if we pass a method reference, a lambda or as in your case, an object instantiated with `new`. `Supplier` is a generic interface taking one type argument. The documentation also tells us that `orElseThrow` expects a `Supplier<? extends X>` where `X extends Throwable`, that is, `X` is a subtype of `Throwable`. So passing a `Supplier<Throwable>` is not incorrect, but as you experienced, it gave you some trouble elsewhere. And we are allowed to put in any subtype of `Throwable` instead. Putting in either `RuntimeException` or `EmployeeNotFoundException` frees us from the trouble.

I don’t know why you should want to be so wordy, though, when the lambda is working fine.

**Link:** [Documentation of the `Supplier` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is answered very easily by looking at the JavaDoc for Optional:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

The lambda parameter is a supplier which supplies an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

`orElseThrow` is a method of the `Optional` class having the following signature:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X
```

This means the lambda expression you are passing must conform to the `Supplier<? extends X>` functional interface. The `Supplier<T>` functional interface has a single method that accepts no arguments and returns an instance of `T`: `T get()`.

Your lambda expression - `() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id)` - matches this functional interface.

This functional interface's `get()` method is used to create the `Throwable` instance that `orElseThrow()` would throw when the `Optional` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

[`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) takes a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and this `Supplier` is used to get an instance of `Exception` which will be thrown if `Optional` has `null` value underneath. See the implementation for `Optional::orElseThrow` :

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {
    if (this.value != null) {
        return this.value;
    } else {
        throw (Throwable)exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

it simply checks if value is there and if not - it gets the Execption instance from `Supplier` and throws it.

And the expression :

```
() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id)
```

is conformant to `Supplier` expected by `Optional::orElseThrow` method - `Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier` where `X` extends `Throwable`. It could be even extracted to separate variable :

```
Supplier<EmployeeNotFoundException> execptionSupplier = () -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
Employee employee = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(execptionSupplier);
```